# Change range datepicker (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have a question regarding jquery.ui datepicker.
I have a project where the week starts on Friday.

That I have no problem with that.

The thing is datepicker not find the way to make the select that I have for weeks, beginning with Friday and also select default Thursday click anywhere for that week.

In summary:

1. **Week Starts Thursday.**
2. **The Selection of the week begins Thursday (range)**
3. **OnSelect Automatically switches to the selected week Thursday.**

Can you help?

My code:

```
$(function() {
var startDate;
var endDate;

var selectCurrentWeek = function() {
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        $('.week-picker').find('.ui-datepicker-current-day a').addClass('ui-state-active')
    }, 1);
}

$('.week-picker').datepicker( {
    showOtherMonths: true,
    selectOtherMonths: true,
    firstDay: 5,
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
    maxDate : "+0",
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 
        var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
        startDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - date.getDay());
        endDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - date.getDay() + 6);
        var dateFormat = inst.settings.dateFormat || $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat;
        $('#startDate').text($.datepicker.formatDate( dateFormat, startDate, inst.settings ));
        $('#endDate').text($.datepicker.formatDate( dateFormat, endDate, inst.settings ));

        selectCurrentWeek();

         //window.location = '<?php echo HTTP_URI; ?>ranking/week?day=' + dateText + '';
    },
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        var cssClass = '';
        if(date >= startDate && date <= endDate)
            cssClass = 'ui-datepicker-current-day';
        return [true, cssClass];
    },
    onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month, inst) {
        selectCurrentWeek();
    }
});

$('.week-picker .ui-datepicker-calendar tr').live('mousemove', function() { $(this).find('td a').addClass('ui-state-hover'); });
$('.week-picker .ui-datepicker-calendar tr').live('mouseleave', function() { $(this).find('td a').removeClass('ui-state-hover'); });
```

});

Comment: *"I have a project where the week starts on Friday"*...  and then *"In summary: Week Starts Thursday."* - What??!!

Comment: uuuups! Sorry, start on Friday, finally ;)

Answer (score 0):

Yeep! I find my own solution.
My code

```
$(function() {

var selectCurrentWeek = function(callback) {
   window.setTimeout(function () {
       $(".week-picker").find("a.ui-state-active").parents("tr").find("a.ui-state-default").each(function(key, node) {
          $(this).addClass("ui-state-active");
        });
         callback();
      }, 1);
}

$('.week-picker').datepicker( {
    showOtherMonths: true,
    selectOtherMonths: true,
    firstDay: 5,
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
    maxDate : "+0",
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 

          selectCurrentWeek(function() {

              var startDayy = $(".week-picker").find("a.ui-state-active").eq(0);
              var EndDayy = $(".week-picker").find("a.ui-state-active").eq(6);

              var startDay = startDayy.text();
              var EndDay= EndDayy.text();
              var monthStart = startDayy.parent().attr('data-month');
              var monthEnd= EndDayy.parent().attr('data-month');
              var yearStart = startDayy.parent().attr('data-year');
              var yearEnd = EndDayy.parent().attr('data-year');

              if(monthStart < 10){ monthStart = '0'+monthStart; } 
              if(monthEnd < 10){ monthEnd = '0'+monthEnd; } 

              var CompleteStartDay = startDay +'/'+ monthStart +'/'+yearStart;
              var CompleteEndDay = EndDay +'/'+ monthEnd +'/'+yearEnd;

              $('#startDate').text(CompleteStartDay);
              $('#endDate').text(CompleteEndDay);

             //window.location = '<?php echo HTTP_URI; ?>ranking/week?day=' + CompleteStartDay + '';

          });

    }

});
```

});